# Workflow Report by person

Tags: 2010, workflow

I am using the approval workflow to assign a list of documents to various employees.  I know you can click on the individual documents to see who has and has not signed off, but is there any way to get a report for each employee so I can see what documents that person was assigned and the status of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Workflow Tasks list will help you out.

click View All Site Content, and then click Tasks. you should able to see the assigned tasks and respective status.

You can create custom views based on that list. to show status wise documents and assigned person name.

Comment: Mark it as answer if this help you